# Change background colour of table cell without altering table or <td> class

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to generate a table from an array. There is no problem styling the table using normal methods but what I want to do is change an individual table cell's background depending on the entry in the cell. Normally you could add a class to the `<td>` tag to do this but because of the way codeigniter is generating the table I can't add any class information to a single cell.

So my question is can I add some css to an element within the cell that will effectively fill the cell? The table is responsive and I would rather not use a background image.

Comment: you can use `style="color:#f00"` in the <td> ?

Comment: If I understood correctly the class should be added depending on the content of the cell? Can't you target the table with jQuery and apply the class to the desired cells with a function?

Comment: do you use codeigniter html table helper to draw a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<td><span class="block-level-span-with-a-red-bg">I'm a block-level span</span></td>

.block-level-span-with-a-red-bg {
    display:block;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Do you have control of the td contents like that?

You'll probably need to border-collapse: collapse the table to remove any gaps

Comment: This looks like just the ticket. I had been trying something similar but forgetting the display:block. Will check this works and then mark as the answer